# selenium - for loop accumulating previous results

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

Code works but the results are accumulating the previous one, please help me thankyou.

url=https://www.bbc.com/news/world

```
news_search = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gs-c-promo gs-t-News nw-c-promo gs-o-faux-block-link gs-u-pb gs-u-pb+@m nw-p-default gs-c-promo--inline gs-c-promo--stacked@xl gs-c-promo--flex']")
title = []
link = []

for search in news_search:
    title.append(search.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text']").text)
    link.append(search.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@class='gs-c-promo-heading gs-o-faux-block-link__overlay-link gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__anchor']").get_attribute('href'))
    print(f'Title:{title}\nLink:{link}')
driver.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were printing the list of all titles and links, rather than the current one. Change it to the following:

```
news_search = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gs-c-promo gs-t-News nw-c-promo gs-o-faux-block-link gs-u-pb gs-u-pb+@m nw-p-default gs-c-promo--inline gs-c-promo--stacked@xl gs-c-promo--flex']")
titles = []
links = []

for search in news_search:
    title = search.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text']").text
    link = search.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@class='gs-c-promo-heading gs-o-faux-block-link__overlay-link gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__anchor']").get_attribute('href')
    print(f'Title:{title}\nLink:{link}')
    titles.append(title)
    links.append(link)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there, you just need to add a dot `.` for the `title` element XPath expression as following:

```py
news_search = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gs-c-promo gs-t-News nw-c-promo gs-o-faux-block-link gs-u-pb gs-u-pb+@m nw-p-default gs-c-promo--inline gs-c-promo--stacked@xl gs-c-promo--flex']")
title = []
link = []

for search in news_search:
    title.append(search.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text']").text)
    link.append(search.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@class='gs-c-promo-heading gs-o-faux-block-link__overlay-link gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__anchor']").get_attribute('href'))
    print(f'Title:{title}\nLink:{link}')
driver.quit()
```

`//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text']` XPath will return the first match for this locator on the entire DOM while if you use this expression with leading dot `.` it will locate the element **inside** the `search` web element `.//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text']`

Answer (score 1):

The following minor adjustments can rectify and improve the performance of your program significantly:

- The *`<h3>`* elements are unique elements.
- The relevant *`<a>`* elements are the *ancestor* of the *`<h3>`*.
- Using the above two login you can avoid the search for *`news_search`*

Your optimized code block is:

```
driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.bbc.com/news/world'})
titles = [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text']")]
links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text']//ancestor::a[1]")]
for i,j in zip(titles, links): print(f"{i} link is {j}")
driver.quit()
```

Console Output:

```
Ukraine nuclear workers: We're kept at gunpoint link is https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-62509638
US justice department seeks to unseal Trump warrant link is https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-62512360
Rollercoaster crash at Legoland Germany injures 31 link is https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-62512359
France battles 'monster' wildfire near Bordeaux link is https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-62503775
Disabled children abused in Ukraine, warns UN link is https://www.bbc.com/news/disability-62513459
Aggressive dolphin bites two more Japanese swimmers link is https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-62508073
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add a "." in your title.append function like this:

```
    title.append(search.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text']").text)
```